# Create raster in R - distance to line feature

Tags: raster, r

I have some line features (eg. 1000 meter isobath), and I would like to make a raster file for my study area where the value of each cell is the distance to the line feature.
Any idea what function I would use in R to accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some SpatialLines object `Sl` and some raster `r` compute distances from each feature in `Sl` to the raster points with:

```
require(rgeos)
dd = gDistance(Sl, as(r,"SpatialPoints"), byid=TRUE)
```

This creates a matrix with a column for each feature in `Sl`. To get the nearest distance to any feature, apply `min` over rows:

```
r[] = apply(dd,1,min)
plot(r)
```

[image]

To reproduce this, create `Sl` as per the example in `class?SpatialLines` and create `r` as `r = raster(extent(Sl))`. Adjust the raster creation with whatever resolution and extent you really need.

If you have a lot of line features then you might want to merge them into one feature so that the return from `gDistance` isn't a huge matrix. You can do that with `gUnion(Sl, Sl)`.

Comment: I got the following erroer: error in r[]=apply(dd, 1, min); dim(x) must have a positive length

Comment: Is that with *your* data or the exact example I've given? Because if its your data then your `dd` object isn't what it should be and only you can investigate that unless you give us your data.

Comment: is there an sf solution to this...?

Comment: @B.Davis convert the sf features to sp, use this?